# Can someone identify this plant/flower?

Tags: roses

As the title says, I'm looking for what kind of plant this is.
[image]

Comment: I think it is [Chinese rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_chinensis), called yueji in chinese. It appears to be one because of the petals that are not exactly cup shaped,kind of flat and the markings, the pale longitudinal striations on the petals.See [Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/yueji).

Comment: It's a rose.  More information on where you found it would help - if growing in someone's garden, then it could be any one of a number of named hybrids.  Asking a gardening or rose-specific forum would likely get a better answer.

Comment: The upright facing of the flower, the fact that each flower seems to be solitary on the stem, and the size of the flowers compared to the size of leaves make me think this is a hybrid tea rose.

Answer (score 3):

Very possibly a Peace Rose (*Rosa Madame de Meilland*), check out images on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Peace), and note that the coloration of the petals can vary according to climatic and other conditions but is basically a yellow petal with crimson/red/pink tinge at the extremities. It is remarkable for its size as a flower and is very popular in gardens.